# parse.com updating user email issue with javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, cordova, email, parse-platform

I am having this issue when i try to update users email with javascript SDK on parse.com

- When the email is available, everything works fine.
- When the email is not available, i get the normal error. Then, I change the email address to another that is available, and save user data again. Here, the problem is that PARSE returns the error 203 again (the email is taken). And if i hit the button to save again, it works! without changing anything!

Maybe is a cache problem, i have been losing time on this little issue. Please can you help me with this?

Here is the code:

```js
// Button
$("#perfil_guardar_btn").on( "vclick", function( event ) {
  actualizar_perfil();
});

// Function to save new user data
function actualizar_perfil() {
    show_loading();
    var new_nombre = $('#edit_nombre').val();
    var new_apellido = $('#edit_apellido').val();
    var new_correo = $('#edit_email').val();
    var new_telefono = $('#edit_telefono').val();
    var new_nacimiento = $('#edit_nacimiento').val();
    var new_genero = $('#edit_genero').val();
    var new_notificaciones = $('#edit_notificaciones').val();

    var emailfilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (emailfilter.test(new_correo) && new_nombre.length >=3 && new_apellido.length >=3 && new_telefono.length >=7) {
        currentUser.fetch().then(
            function(fetchedUser){
                // objeto de usuario
                var fetchUser = null;
                fetchUser = fetchedUser;
                alert(fetchUser.get("email"));
                // Poner nuevos datos
                fetchUser.set("nombre", new_nombre);
                fetchUser.set("apellido", new_apellido);
                fetchUser.set("email", new_correo);
                alert(fetchUser.get("email"));
                fetchUser.set("telefono", new_telefono);
                if(new_nacimiento != ""){
                    var new_nacimiento_formatted = new Date(new_nacimiento);
                    fetchUser.set("nacimiento", new_nacimiento_formatted);
                }
                if(new_genero != "No"){
                    fetchUser.set("genero", new_genero);
                }
                if(new_notificaciones == "no"){
                    fetchUser.set("notificaciones", false);
                }
                else if(new_notificaciones == "si"){
                    fetchUser.set("notificaciones", true);
                }

                // Save the user.
                fetchUser.save(null, {
                    success: function(anotherUser) {
                        refreshUser();
                        navigator.notification.alert(
                            'Tus datos han sido actualizados.',
                            alertDismissed,
                            'Correcto',
                            'OK'
                        );
                    },
                    error: function(gameScore, error) {
                        switch(error.code){
                            case 202:
                                navigator.notification.alert(
                                    'Este usuario ya está registrado en DORA',
                                    alertDismissed,
                                    'Error',
                                    'OK'
                                );
                                break;
                            case 203:
                                navigator.notification.alert(
                                    'Revisa tus datos y vuelve a intentarlo. Es posible que este correo ya esté en uso.',
                                    alertDismissed,
                                    'Error',
                                    'OK'
                                );
                                break;
                            default:
                                navigator.notification.alert(
                                    'Hubo un error en el registro. Intenta de nuevo',
                                    alertDismissed,
                                    'Error',
                                    'OK'
                                );
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 
            function(error){
                // Error
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    'Ha ocurrido un error inesperado. Vuelve a intentarlo',
                    alertDismissed,
                    'Error',
                    'OK'
                );
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'Por favor completa los datos. Nombre, apellido, correo y teléfono son obligatorios.',
            alertDismissed,
            'Error',
            'OK'
        );
    }
}
```